PowerBI need to show certain dates and data from different tables that do not contain dates
I need some hint how to do one thing in PowerBI.
Attaching sample of model:

I have Calendar table related to Dates from Sign_up_dates which is connected to Provider_info table by ProviderID. Then I have 3 tables without date information, only ProviderID which is connected to Provider_info table. There are no dates, as information there is for the last week. We can see there Sales, Discount and info about offers.
What I need in visualization of table, is when I choose date of Sign up, I want to see only those providers in table who were sign up in chosen dates. Also I need to see all providers even without data, as I need to check if our client hasn't implement any of offer, disount or there are no sales. In this case information will be duplicated for each day in chosen period.
I tried to add column in all 3 tables with date information,it didn't help.
And also tried to create new table from all these tables, but some of information like sales are aggregated for each provider, but some like offers Varchar can be several rows for one provider.
Also I could see as a solution to delete dates from table visualization and make separate table with providers and dates of setup and if you click on each you will see result in other visualizations, but I would like to see dates with information in one table visualization.
Thank you for any idea

Does the sales transaction have a relationship with the sign-up ?
I mean do you record the sign-up date only when the provider makes a transaction ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
